# Is there a methodology and a well stablished library for Data Visualization in Big Data?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using pyspark for develope a ML proyecto. I'm going to start with the *exploratory data analysis* and I am using jupyter notebooks. I want to do some scatter plots and apply other visualization techniques for the EDA, but I don't know what specific technologies, methodologies and frameworks are available for do that from python/pyspark/jupyter notebooks.

Any help will be wellcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://datashader.org/ this might help

Comment: Seems it will help me a lot. Thanks !